# Pytesser in Python 3.4: name 'image_to_string' is not defined?

Tags: python, ocr

First off, I would like to say that I know pytesser is not for Python 3.4, but I read from http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1916011.html  that pytesser should also work for Python 3.
I just installed pytesser and I am trying to read a file.

```
from pytesser import *
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('/Users/William/Documents/Science/PYTHON/textArea01.png')
```

No problems there, but when I use

```
print (image_to_string(image))
```

it comes up with this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    print (image_to_string(image))
NameError: name 'image_to_string' is not defined
```

Comment: Please show us the whole code. Your error says `File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>`, hence, you did no importing

Comment: I just looked at the source.... it does not appear to me that it would be Python 3 compatible... the only reason I say that is that it imports StringIO at the top.

Comment: @Haidro My whole code is already what I posted. The import was done in the 'from pytesser import *' part.

Comment: Yes, but in your error, it says that `print (image_to_string(image))` is the first line

Comment: @Haidro Well, I was typing all this in the shell, I used print(image_to_string(image)) after all the other stuff. Should I have done this in a script?

Comment: Try that. When I use the interactive interpreter, it works fine for me. But it could be the fact that this doesn't work for python 3 (I was using 2.7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will not work for Python 3. The reason is because when you do `from pytesser import *` (or simply import it in the first place), the `if __name__ == '__main__'` conditional will be True, and the code below it will run.

As I'm sure you're aware, in Python 3, `print` is no longer a statement but a function. Hence, a `SyntaxError` will occur at the line `print text`.

I'm not sure why you're not seeing this `SyntaxError` in your code, but if this error passed silently, that means that nothing was imported in the first place, hence the error.

To fix this, use Python 2.7.

Python 2.7:

```
>>> from pytesser import *
>>> print image_to_string
<function image_to_string at 0x10057ec08>
```

Python 3:

```
>>> from pytesser import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "./pytesser.py", line 61
    print text
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using the module pytesseract Python 3. You may need to change the import statement in **init**.py for the pytesser module and add a leading dot. For pytesseract running 2to3-3.4 on **init**.py it changed from:

`from pytesseract import image_to_string`

to

`from .pytesseract import image_to_string`

and then it can resolve the image_to_string function.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem like this:

```
from pytesseract import pytesseract as pytesser
from PIL import Image
```