# No module name PIL and No module name pytesser Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, anaconda, ocr

I have installed Anaconda on windows after my Python3.4 installation.

I'm referring this link : http://benedict-chan.github.io/blog/2014/11/07/setup-python-environment-in-visual-studio/ to setup anaconda from my VS2015 and Windows 10 like this:

[image]

I have written the following code by referring this : http://www.manejandodatos.es/2014/11/ocr-python-easy/  to read text from an image.

However, I'm getting below error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Moreover, When I checked back the setting (from Tools ->Options) as below, its setting to default Python34.

[image]
Is it that, the Anaconda setting is not persistent , due to which the run time error is showing up?

Note: When I tried to install PIL using pip its saying PIL is install during Anaconda installation.

Edit:

The PIL error is resolved by setting Anaconda as default environment like below:

[image]

However, I'm getting same kind of error on the next line. That is "No module name pytesser"

Note: I was following this ( http://techqa.info/programming/tag/ocr?after=39453936 ); When I tried to install "tesseract" using pip its saying : Requirement already satisfied - Below message

```
 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pytesser>pip install tesseract

   Requirement already satisfied: tesseract in 
   c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
```

As per this( [Pytesser in Python 3.4: name 'image_to_string' is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874106/pytesser-in-python-3-4-name-image-to-string-is-not-defined) ) . It looks like it only support 2.7 version, but not 3.. Still,

How can I resolve this? 
Please suggest? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried pip install Pillow? Pillow is a maintained fork of PIL. Pillow can also get imported via import PIL.

Comment: Could you please guide me in which directory I should install Pillow? Will it be under Anaconda distribution or under Python34? The PIL error is gone now as I set Anaconda my default environment. Now I'm getting an error for "pytesser". I have edited my question.Will Pillow installation help me reading text from the images? Please suggest me any link.