# How to install pytesser on Debian?

Tags: python, debian, pytesser

I want to use **image_to_string** in my python script for reading numbers from image.
i import  everything from pytesser
`from pytesser import *`

i read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874106/pytesser-in-python-3-4-name-image-to-string-is-not-defined) and

i installed **pytesseract**

```
 pip install pytesseract
```

and **tesseract-ocr**

```
apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

but i have **already** this error!

```
ImportError: No module named pytesser
```

What's wrong with my installation?

Comment: what python are you using to launch the script? You could be installing for 2 and running for 3, or vice versa

Comment: @omu_negru i installed python 2.7.3 and i use #!/usr/bin/python2.7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try adjusting the import statement from

```
from pytesser import *
```

to

```
from pytesseract import *
```